# swicthing format on dates using the datetimepicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datetimepicker

I'm using the datetimepicker to get two dates. They are coming out like this: 24-11-2011..

I want to have them like this: `2011-11-24`..

I've tried to accomplish this by doing this method, but its only changes the datetimepicker on the interface..

```
DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom; 
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

This is my code. The output says `24-11-2011`. I want it to say `2011-11-24`.

```
 string sta = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
 string en = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString();
 Console.WriteLine(sta);
 ctrscan.getListOfDates(sta, en);
```

How can I do this?

thanks

Comment: Its not entirely clear what you're asking - is the problem with the display of data in the date picker or with the format of the date elsewhere in your application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Value` property of the DateTimePicker control will return DateTime type, not string.

To format this have such code:

```
string myDate = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

To change it "globally" change the default in the machine Regional Settings.

Answer (score 0):

Change your System Date Format  then only it will display correctly using  `Console.WriteLine(sta);`